# I cant access to "/login" from path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If I write "http://localhost:3000/login" in the url field on chrome, i cant access to this component. But, if i put a `<Link to="/login">`, there isn't problem, the component rendered perfectly.

my App.js code:

```
<AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <AnonRoute 
              path='/' 
              exact
              render={(props) => <><Landing {...props} /></>} />
            <AnonRoute 
              exact
              path="/login" 
              render={(props) =>  <LoginForm {...props}/>} />
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path="/grid"
              render={(props) => <><Menu/> <Home {...props} /> </>} />

            <AnonRoute component={NotFound}/>

          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
```

AnonRoute, PrivateRoute has:

```
{!isLoggedIn ?  <Route render={render} {...rest}/> : <Redirect to="/"/>}
```

I don't know how identify the way of error... If anyone need more code, let me know, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't handle the /login in the backend. You can handle the whole thing from the front end by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter. Or you can handle it from the backend by return the html page to all the routes. Take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/hashrouter-demo

Comment: well, but i never used that, and always work... i dont know why! https://github.com/prrrcl/ementh (for ex. in my backend, i didnt handle /login route)

Comment: what server you are using to deploy your react app

Comment: I found the issue! create-react-app give me the fallback, but my actual project isnt a create-react-app